# Swift 2 How to change public var string

Tags: ios, string, swift2

I have Menu class and i have another view i want to change menu class title item in another item my codes here.

Menuitemfile.

```
public class MediumMenuItem: NSObject {
    public var title:String?
    public var completion: completionHandler?

    override private init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public convenience init(title: String, completion: completionHandler) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.completion = completion
    }
}
```

**Config file**

```
var title1 = ""
var title2 = ""
var title3 = ""
```

**View Controller**

```
    class NavigationController: UINavigationController {





        override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
            super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        var menu: MediumMenu?




        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()




    let myURL: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://bla.com/title_api.php")
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "title=1"


    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }else{

            if let unwrappedData = data {

                let string1 =  NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)



                let fullNameArr = string1!.componentsSeparatedByString(",")


                title1 = fullNameArr[0]
                title2 = fullNameArr[1]
                title3 = fullNameArr[2]



                topURL1 = fullNameArr[3]
                topURL2 = fullNameArr[4]
                topURL3 = fullNameArr[5]






            }
        }


    }


    task.resume()




    let item2 = MediumMenuItem(title: title1) {
        let topStoriesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Web1") as! WebViewController1
        self.setViewControllers([topStoriesViewController], animated: false)
    }



    let item3 = MediumMenuItem(title: title2) {
        let bookMarksViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Web2") as! WebViewController2
        self.setViewControllers([bookMarksViewController], animated: false)
    }



    let item4 = MediumMenuItem(title: title3) {
        let bookMarksViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Web3") as! WebViewController3
        self.setViewControllers([bookMarksViewController], animated: false)
    }
```

}

**Remote Json File Output**

```
New1,New2,New3,http://www.bla.com,http://www.bla.com,http://www.bla.com
```

**Xcode Output**

```
No error and title1,title2,title3 showing blank in my app ( not showing)
```

I added all codes i need your help thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weite your let declaration for the menu in the response block from your session, after setting the title. The current declaration will not get the ne w titles because the request is started asynchron.

That means the request is running and the code is still going forward to the end .

Anyways, it looks very strange what you try to do. Think on a Manager that makes the work of calling the items, and use Controller to Call it. With the response you should create your Navigation Controller and fill it with your Items. Still strange, but the Navigation Controller is made for navigation ;)

Comment: :) yeah i think so navigation controller class also have i added controller codes from there :)  I think need expert code. still waiting :-II

Comment: well, create your items in the response block and you should go ahead. But what you really want, is that someone writes a menu for u or what?